# Merge conditional expression C#

Tags: c#, resharper

I need my code to use conditional expression, but not sure how to fix this correct.

Here is the "old" code:

```
private int PageNumber
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["PageNumber"] != null)
        {
            return (int)ViewState["PageNumber"];
        }
        return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["PageNumber"] = value;
    }
}
```

Below is the "new" code. I have tried to modify the "old" code, but get "Merge conditional expression" in "get":

```
private int PageNumber
{
    get => ViewState["PageNumber"] != null ? (int) ViewState["PageNumber"] : 0;
    set => ViewState["PageNumber"] = value;
}
```

How can "get" use conditional expression?

Comment: Have you read [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/MergeConditionalExpression.html)?

Comment: "Merge conditional expression" sounds like Resharper is suggesting an improvement. There's probably a way to tell it to make that improvement: I'm guessing it will do something like `(ViewState["PageNumber"] as int?) ?? 0` or `(int?)ViewState["PageNumber"] ?? 0`

Comment: If Resharper is suggesting something, then tell it to implement that suggestion for you...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, ReSharper does not propose a solution. But it likes the following more than your solution.

```cs
private int PageNumber
{
    get => (int)(ViewState["PageNumber"] ?? 0);
    set => ViewState["PageNumber"] = value;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `(int?)` there?

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked:

private int PageNumber
{
    get => (int)(ViewState["PageNumber"] ?? 0);
    set => ViewState["PageNumber"] = value;
}

Comment: @canton7 No. It's never null. If ViewState["PageNumber"] is null, then 0 is returned
 because of the null-coalescing operator.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Comment: Ah, didn't spot the brackets were that way around. That's more confusion than `(int?)ViewState["PageNumber"] ?? 0` IMO, as this version avoids casting `0` to `int`, but your choice